# D3 stack() skipping first object in my data array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I am building a stacked bar chart using d3 v4.4.4 in react.js v15.3.0. Below is the data I am using to build my stacked bar chart:

```
[
    { timestamp: "2006", source1: "20", source2: "20", source3: "20", source4: '20'},
    { timestamp: "2007", source1: "70", source2: "50", source3: "10", source4: '70'},
    { timestamp: "2008", source1: "80", source2: "50", source3: "60", source4: '40'},
    { timestamp: "2009", source1: "30", source2: "20", source3: "40", source4: '50'},
    { timestamp: "2010", source1: "70", source2: "20", source3: "90", source4: '20'}
]
```

I have gotten the stacked bar chart to show up [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KceQS.png), but it is not showing the first object in the array of data. Instead the stacked bar chart duplicates the last object in the array of data and uses for both the first and last stacked bar in the chart.

```
const stack = d3.stack().keys(keys)

const layers = stack(chartDataWorkingCopy)
```

[this was the result of logging layers to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ykxS.png)

As you can see from the screenshot above the first and last arrays are the same, and the first object (i.e. { timestamp: "2006", source1: "20", source2: "20", source3: "20", source4: '20'}) from the original data I used to build the chart is not there.

Can someone explain to me why d3 is skipping over the first object in the array and duplicating the last when building the stacked bar chart?

Below is the source code for the stacked bar chart component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import _ from 'lodash'

class StackedBarChart extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    chartData: PropTypes.array,
    barWidth: PropTypes.number,
    barOffset: PropTypes.number,
    chartHeight: PropTypes.number,
    chartWidth: PropTypes.number
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    chartData:  [
        { timestamp: "2006", source1: "20", source2: "20", source3: "20", source4: '20'},
        { timestamp: "2007", source1: "70", source2: "50", source3: "10", source4: '70'},
        { timestamp: "2008", source1: "80", source2: "50", source3: "60", source4: '40'},
        { timestamp: "2009", source1: "30", source2: "20", source3: "40", source4: '50'},
        { timestamp: "2010", source1: "70", source2: "20", source3: "90", source4: '20'}
    ],
    barWidth: 10,
    barOffset: 5,
    chartHeight: 200,
    chartWidth: 300
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(!_.isEqual(this.props, prevProps)){
      d3.select('svg').remove()
      this.renderChart()
    }
  }

  splitTheDifference(data) {
    let str = String(data)
    const points = str.split(',')
    return (points[1] - points[0])
  }

  renderChart() {
    const { chartData, barWidth, barOffset, chartHeight, chartWidth} = this.props

    let chartDataWorkingCopy = [...chartData]

    // keep the bars from going off the page 
    const maxBars = (chartWidth / (barWidth + 2))

    if (chartDataWorkingCopy.length > maxBars) {
      chartDataWorkingCopy = chartDataWorkingCopy.slice(-Math.floor(maxBars))
    }

    const keys = _.remove(_.keys(_.extend.apply({}, chartDataWorkingCopy)), (d) => {
      return d !== 'timestamp'
    })

   const xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, chartWidth]).padding(0.1)
   const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([chartHeight, 0])
   const color = ['hsl(8, 82%, 50%)', 'hsl(76, 96%, 50%)', 'hsl(178, 99%, 50%)', 'hsl(302, 100%, 50%)', 'hsl(58, 98%, 50%)', 'hsl(144, 100%, 50%)']
   const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
   const yAxis =  d3.axisLeft(yScale)
   const width =  chartWidth 
   const height = chartHeight

   let svg = d3.select('.barChartContainer').append("svg")
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')

    const stack = d3.stack().keys(keys)

    const layers = stack(chartDataWorkingCopy)
        xScale.domain(chartDataWorkingCopy.map(function(d) { return d.timestamp }))
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) { 
          return d[0] + d[1]
        }) ]).nice()

    const layer = svg.selectAll('.layer')
            .data(layers)
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('class', 'layer')
            .style('fill', function(d, i) { return color[i] })

      layer.selectAll("rect")
              .data(function(d) {
          return d
        })
            .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
            return i * 12
        })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]) })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]) })
              .attr("width", 10)
        .on('mouseover', (d) => {
          d3.select('#tooltip')
            .classed('hidden', false)
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#333333')
            .style('color', '#fff')
            .style('padding', 10)
            .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX}px`)
            .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 80}px`)
            .select('#value')
              .text(this.splitTheDifference(d))
        })
        .on('mouseout', (d) => {
          d3.select('#tooltip')
            .classed('hidden', true)
        })



  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div className={ 'barChartContainer' }>
        <div id='tooltip' className='hidden'>
          <p id='value'></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StackedBarChart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `d3.stack()` is not skipping the first object in your data array.

The problem is that this code...

```
const keys = _.remove(_.keys(_.extend.apply({}, chartDataWorkingCopy)), (d) => {
    return d !== 'timestamp'
})
```

... is not only getting the keys, but also modifying your `chartDataWorkingCopy` array, which **still points** to your `chartData` array.

Right now, you may think that you're cloning your original array here:

```
let chartDataWorkingCopy = [...chartData];
```

But, unfortunately, you're not. You cannot clone an array of objects with the spread operator. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) says:

> Typically the spread operators in ES2015 goes one level deep while copying an array. Therefore, they are unsuitable for copying multidimensional arrays. It's the same case with Object.assign() and Object spread operators. Look at the example below for a better understanding.

So, in your code, any change to `chartDataWorkingCopy` also changes `chartData`.

**Solution 01**

You can get the keys without modifying the array, using vanilla JS or D3, you don't need lodash for this. For instance, this is a very simple way to get the keys you want using only D3 and without modifying the source array:

```
const keys = d3.keys(chartDataWorkingCopy[0]).filter(d => d != "timestamp");
```

**Solution 02**

If you want to keep your lodash function, use a method that really copies a deep array, like this:

```
let chartDataWorkingCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartData));
```

In this demo, I'm keeping your code (with lodash), just changing the code that makes a copy of the original array. Now the values are correct:

```js
var chartData = [
    { timestamp: "2006", source1: "20", source2: "20", source3: "20", source4: '20'},
    { timestamp: "2007", source1: "70", source2: "50", source3: "10", source4: '70'},
    { timestamp: "2008", source1: "80", source2: "50", source3: "60", source4: '40'},
    { timestamp: "2009", source1: "30", source2: "20", source3: "40", source4: '50'},
    { timestamp: "2010", source1: "70", source2: "20", source3: "90", source4: '20'}
  ];

let chartDataWorkingCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartData));


const keys = _.remove(_.keys(_.extend.apply({}, chartDataWorkingCopy)), (d) => {
    return d !== 'timestamp'
})


const stack = d3.stack().keys(keys)

const layers = stack(chartData);

console.log(layers);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Copying an array with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` only works if you don't have actual date objects in that array. Right now, "2006", "2007", "2008" and so on are only strings, so this method works.